# After Insert events for pre-2007 MS Access

Tags: events, ms-access, vbscript

I need to execute a script (some sort of macro or VB script) that posts data to a different server every time a record is added or changed on a local MS Access database. This is trivial on a 2007 or later .accdb file with After Events but I need to accomplish the same effect on a 2000 formatted .mdb file. Does anyone know of a way to simulate an 'after create' event on this older database type?

Comment: If you are using a form, then After Update and After Insert. Data macros date to the 2010 version. I do not think I have seen after create.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "After Insert"